# Computername in output from foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to do a simple thing of listing a computername in an output from a foreach loop, but I just can’t seem to get it working, was hoping someone could point me in the right direction..

I’ve tried the below

```
$computers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like ‘vm-*'").Name | Sort-Object
foreach ($computer in $Computers) 
{
Get-Service -Name RpcSs | Select Name, Status, computername
}
```

Thanks

Comment: With this code you will alwasy get the services from the local machine and not from the computer which is in the variable

Comment: @guiwhatsthat  thanks, so do I need to add $computer or $($conputer) instead of computername after select?

Comment: Use the -computername paramter of the get-service cmdlet

Comment: The code inside your loop doesn't reference the `$computer` variable at all.

Comment: Thanks all I’ve added -conputername $computer in the get-service, that then hits every machine, but the output doesn’t list computername and service and status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the $computer in the get-servie cmdlet. In your code you will always get the services of the local computer.

Try like this:

```
$computers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like ‘vm-*'").Name
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) 
{
    Get-Service -Name RpcSs -ComputerName $Computer| Select-Object -Property Name, Status, MachineName
}
```